# Groovy inject works locally but not on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have the following script in a Jenkins () pipeline:

```
def imageTags = []
def semVerMatch = 'v0.0.0' =~ /(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(-.*)?$/
if (semVerMatch.find()) {
    List<String> versionNumber = semVerMatch[0][1].split("\\.") // e.g. 1.2.3
    String versionSuffix = semVerMatch[0][2] ?: '' // e.g. -rc
    imageTags += versionNumber[1,-1].inject([versionNumber[0]]) { acc, val ->
        acc += "${acc[-1]}.${val}"
    }.collect { "${it}${versionSuffix}" }
}
```

Running locally with the same Groovy version that seems to be used on that Jenkins (Groovy Shell (2.4.13, JVM: 11.0.12), oh my ), I get:

> ===> [0, 0.0, 0.0.0]

for `imageTags`, as expected.

On Jenkins, however, I get an error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
> (Stacktrace useless, as per usual)

By println debugging (no idea how else to proceed), I have determined that `acc == null` in the second "iteration" of `inject`:

[image: Jenkins log showing that all is well until acc==null]

Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: The error indicates you are invoking `getAt` on a `null` reference.  From the limited error shown it isn't clear if that is coming from `semVerMatch[0][1]`, `versionNumber[1,-1]` or `versionNumber[0]`.

Comment: "Stacktrace useless, as per usual" - Can you show the part of the stacktrace which tracks to your code?  That should give you some info to indicate which line of code is invoking the problematic `getAt`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown ad 1) As you can see from my answer, it came from neither. And yes, the fact that isn't clear from the error is a big part of the point/frustration here. ad 2) _Does_ it track to my code? Let's see: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/R9zpXh5). Is `at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:109)` what I'm looking for? Missed that at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a whim I tried adding a final expression to the closure that *definitely* returns the new value of `acc`:

```
imageTags += versionNumber[1,-1].inject([versionNumber[0]]) { acc, val ->
    acc += "${acc[-1]}.${val}"
    acc
}.collect { "${it}${versionSuffix}" }
```

For some reason, *that* works:

[image: Jenkins log showing that all is well]